# Retrieve name of bluetooth device from rfcomm device services

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, windows-10, rfcomm

The context is the following, we have multiple trucks that contains a bluetooth to serial device, we have given each truck bluetooth a unique name to be able to connect to a specific truck.

I use this code to retrieve all the RFComm services  :

```
DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort))
```

The problem is that all the DeviceInformation objects returned contains the name of the RFComm service in the Name property instead of the bluetooth device name. When my project was a Win 8 store app, all was fine since the name property contained the bluetooth device name.

I found that I could create a BluetoothDevice object using the device id returned by the above code, but then the app ask to use the bluetooth device for all devices until I find the good one. I would like to prevent that as it wasn't the case with Win 8 store app.

Second solution I found was to parse the device id of the RFComm service which look like this one

```
Bluetooth#Bluetooth00:c2:c6:56:b0:61-00:15:be:0f:02:d7#RFCOMM:00000000:{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}
```

to remove everything past "#RFCOMM" and use the `DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync()` function. This works but I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution to my problem since parsing a string can be a real problem if the string format change.

Is there a way to retrieve the name of the bluetooth device without having to ask to use all bluetooth device until we find it?

Comment: yes it worked, I marked your answer as accepted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code to get the name of the Bluetooth device:

```
var serviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort), new string[] { "System.Devices.AepService.AepId" });

foreach (var serviceInfo in serviceInfoCollection)
{
    var deviceInfo = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync((string)serviceInfo.Properties["System.Devices.AepService.AepId"]);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Device name is: '{deviceInfo.Name}' and Id is: '{deviceInfo.Id}'");
}
```

The key point here is that Bluetooth device is one type of **AssociationEndpoint** objects. AEPs usually represent a device discovered over a wireless or network protocol. An **AssociationEndpoint** object is a child of a single **AssociationEndpointContainer** object and can contain 0 or more **AssociationEndpointService** objects. And **RFComm service** is one  **AssociationEndpointService** that Bluetooth device contains. For more info, please see [DeviceInformationKind enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationkind.aspx) and [Enumerate devices over a network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187356.aspx).

**AssociationEndpointService** has several properties. One of them is **System.Devices.AepService.AepId** which represents the identifier of the parent **AssociationEndpoint** object. So we can use this property to get the Bluetooth device information and once we get the device information, we can get the device name easily. However **System.Devices.AepService.AepId** property is not a commen property in [DeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation). So we need to use [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(String, IIterable(String))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225434) method to require this additional propertie. For more info, please see [Device information properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties).

Comment: very well explained answer about bluetooth structure thank you!